# App Ionic framework Integrado com Sistema em Java Web JSF

Tags: php, java, jsf

Galera, preciso de uma orientação de algum desenvolvedor experiente, onde, a necessidade é: Tenho uma aplicação criada em Java Web com JSF em produção. Preciso desenvolver um App Híbrido com framework Ionic (multplataforma), para receber notificação e gerar uma tabela de registros, etc. Exemplo1: Quando executar uma atualização na tabela X, pelo Sistema Gerenciador deve notificar no App e permitir visualizar os registros na tabela; Exemplo2: Quando uma pessoa fazer um agendamento pelo App atualizar a tabela X, no Banco de Dados, e pelo Sistema Gerenciador, o ADM consegue visualizar os registros. 
Qual tecnologia é melhor para esta necessidade, que não vai dar problema no futuro devido a quantidade de pessoa usando o aplicativo? Qual tecnologia melhor para fazer a comunicação com o Sistema Gerenciado?

Answer (score 0):

No seu projeto web crie mais uma camada para o webservice, recomendo o jax-rs, e faça com que seu APP consuma essa API.